# SELECT MAX from Counting SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with extracting data from db. My code looks like:

```
SELECT MAX(maximum)as Number FROM 
(
SELECT department_name, COUNT(employees.employee_id) AS maximum
FROM departments, employees
WHERE departments.department_id=employees.department_id
GROUP BY department_name
)t
```

and the result is:

Number

```
1   46
```

and this is the number of maximum employees in one of the departments.
The problem is that i want to have additional column with the name of the department in wich there is 46 employees. I tried something like:

```
select department_name, count(employees.employee_id)
from departments, employees
where departments.department_id=employees.department_id
group by department_name
having count(employees.employee_id) =
( SELECT MAX(maxx)FROM 
(SELECT department_name, COUNT(employees.employee_id) AS maxx
FROM departments, employees
WHERE departments.department_id=employees.department_id
GROUP BY department_name
);
```

but it doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT t.department_name, MAX(t.maximum) as Number FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        department_name, 
        COUNT(employees.employee_id) AS maximum 
    FROM departments, employees 
    WHERE departments.department_id=employees.department_id 
    GROUP BY department_name 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this just order your results by maximum in descending order with limit 1,also use modern join syntax query

```
SELECT d.department_name, 
COUNT(e.employee_id) AS maximum
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN employees e
ON (d.department_id=e.department_id)
GROUP BY d.department_name
ORDER BY maximum DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This will give you the department name who has the highest count of employees

Answer (score 0):

You could also tack on an additional JOIN to the first query you posted as such:

`SELECT TOP 1 d.department_name, MAX(maximum) as Number FROM 
    (
    SELECT department_id AS department_id, COUNT(employees.employee_id) AS maximum
    FROM departments, employees
    WHERE departments.department_id=employees.department_id
    GROUP BY department_id
    )t
    JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = t.department_id
    GROUP BY d.department_name
    ORDER BY Number DESC`

I tried this with a similar data model in my domain and it works quite nicely.